# Have Sublime 2 replace tabs with 4 spaces in Python but 2 spaces in JavaScript?

Tags: sublimetext2, spaces

As the title suggests, I'm trying to set variable tab-for-space replacements according to the file format. Is this possible? I've only been able to set one universal setting for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open up a file of the format you want to set preferences for and do the following:

Click *Sublime Text 2 -> Preferences -> Settings - More -> Syntax Specific - User*

That will open a file for preferences for the format of the file you're editing; e.g., if you're editing a .c file, you'll be setting the preferences for C language files.

Add this to the file that Sublime Text opens after you navigate as above:

`{
    "tab_size": <whatever you want>,
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
}`

Comment: You can also edit language-specific preference files in the Sublime Text Packages folder.